# Require Paypal Subscription to Create an Account - ASP.Net / MVC4 / C# / Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, paypal

I am new to Entity Framework, MVC and Razor but am almost finished with my first project using it.

The final piece of the puzzle is to tweak the "canned" Log-in / Registration piece that comes by default when setting up an MVC project. I need to integrate with Paypal in order to create a monthly subscription. If payment is up-to-date then their account will then allow them to access all the benefits my site has to (hopefully) offer.

I signed up with developer.paypal.com and think I have a good start as far as creating test accounts. I just need to get the code in place.

1. Is there any sample code that already tackles this? I read through the API doc but
2. Is there any best practices that relate to what I want to accomplish? For example, should someone pay first, then create an account or vice versa? Should I have to implement managing their subscription cancellation or do they have to do it within their account? etc...
3. How can I tell if a user is current with their subscription and they didn't cancel.
4. How can I tie a user to their Paypal transaction?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [that](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) give you any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal has Standard Subscriptions and then they have the Recurring Payments API, or what can sometimes be seen as Recurring Billing.  I would definitely recommend going with the API's as it will give you much more freedom to do everything you're wanting.

If you're talking about PayPal payments (where people sign in to pay) I'd go with [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/overview-ec/), which consists if [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), and then [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) and/or [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) depending on what you're doing.  In your case it sounds like you'll be doing CRPP because you're working with subscriptions.

That will return a profile ID which you can save locally in your user table(s).  Then, when people login you can make a call to [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) to lookup the current status of the profile, and then redirect the user to different places depending on the status.

[PayPal's .NET SDK](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet) should make all of those calls easy on you, but it's really just a matter of building NVP requests and sending them to PayPal via HTTP POST.

If you want to do all of that with credit cards directly then the process is the same, but there are different API calls involved, and depending on the version of PayPal account you have the calls would be different.

If you're using Website Payments Pro 3.0 then you would use the [DoDirectPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) platform, which in the case of recurring payments you would just make a single call to [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) and include the credit card details in that request.

If you're on Payments Pro 2.0 that would use the [PayFlow API](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf), and that's where it's called Recurring Billing, so you'd just have to setup a PayFlow request accordingly.

Comment: Thank you VERY much! Very helpful. Can you please fill me in on this Payments Pro 3.0 and 2.0? I've read more  about the CreateReoccuringPaymentsProfile so you had me from everything up until the Website Payments Pro talk.

I was reading up on stuff here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/direct-payment/ht_dp-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/

Comment: Check out this [article I wrote on The History of Payments Pro](http://www.angelleye.com/paypal-payments-pro-dodirectpayment-vs-payflow/) awhile back.  It should help you fully understand it.